# How to select rows with information in a text file by using linux command

Tags: linux

I just want to select certain info in separated rows in a text file. How do I deal with this?
[image]
For selecting row, which contains "SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER" and another row contains "LATEST_OFFLINE_TIME"

My output to look like following:
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER=23481XXXXXX02
LATEST_OFFLINE_TIME=20170330191209

Comment: how about grep: `grep 'SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER\|LATEST_OFFLINE_TIME' file.txt`

Comment: thanks a lot Karsten, your recommendation worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '/'"SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER"'/,/'"LATEST_OFFLINE_TIME"'/' file.txt
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER=1923UIO1U23I1O
LATEST_OFFLINE_TIME=128390812903810983019
```

Comment: thanks LV426, but I received error as:    $: command not found

Comment: The $ is not meant to be entered. The $ signifies that it is written at the command line / prompt. You'll need to know this for future reference on here.

The actual command would be: 



`awk '/'"SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER"'/,/'"LATEST_OFFLINE_TIME"'/' file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

`$ awk '/SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER/,/LATEST_OFFLINE_TIME/' file.txt`

Comment: Hi Kasif, thanks for your posting. However, I tried following your recommendation, but received error as:                                                              $: command not found